Namespace name 'Charting' does not exist in the namespace 'Telerik.Reporting'
We just upgrade our Telerik Reporting .Net Framework project to .Net 8.
And when I rebuild the project, I noticed that the Charting namespace no longer exists.
Error (active) CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Charting' does not exist in the namespace 'Telerik.Reporting' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  MyReportsCore   C:\dev\git-projects\...\SynergyReportsCore\Exams.Designer.cs    284 

Then I find this page: https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/report-items/chart-(obsolete)
What am I supposed to do with over 400 errors pointing to the Charting library ?
I can't just change every Chart ref to Graph. That won't work.
I need either upgrade tool, or perhaps if I can just use our old Framework 4.6 Reports Project within our new Core solution. I just don't know if they will work side-by-side.
Any thoughts or suggestions while I research this issue ? I'll open a Telerik ticket..
